# В чём опасность использования for .. in для объекта или массива?

Tags: javascript, javascript-faq

В чём опасность использования for .. in для объекта или массива?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Как написано в [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

> ## Проход по массиву и for...in
>
> > **Замечание**: `for...in` не следует использовать для [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), где важен порядок индексов.
>
> Индексы массива - перечисляемые свойства с целочисленными именами, а в остальном аналогичны свойствам объектов. Нет гарантии, что `for...in` будет возвращать индексы в нужном порядке и вернёт все перечисляемые свойства, включая имеющие не целочисленные имена и наследуемые.
>
> Поэтому порядок прохода зависит от реализации, проход по массиву может не произойти в правильном порядке. Следовательно лучше с числовыми индексами использовать циклы [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for), [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) или [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), когда проходим по массивам, где важен порядок доступа к свойствам.

Comment: Ну и перевод у них там! «пер**и**числяемые свойства, включая имеющие нецелочисл**ин**енные»

Comment: @VladD, чуть поправил

Comment: Там есть кнопка «редактировать», кстати :)

Comment: @VladD, в mdn? :)

Comment: Ага, где ж ещё :)

Comment: @VladD, здесь еще :)

Answer (score 9):

## Для объекта:

- Перебираются все ключи, в том числе унаследованные:

  ```
  var obj = {a: 9};

  Object.prototype.myAwfulThing = 8;

  for (var key in obj) {
    console.log(key);
  }
  ```

  При этом унаследованное свойство может быть добавлено какой-то библиотекой.

  Поэтому рекомендуется делать проверку на наличие свойства в самом объекте:

  ```
  var obj = {a: 9};

  Object.prototype.myAwfulThing = 8;

  for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      console.log(key);
    }
  }
  ```
- Даже если ты на 100% уверен, что унаследованных свойств нет, библиотеками никакими не пользуешься и всё замечательно работает, браузер-то об этом не знает.

  <s>Браузер оптимизирует только случай, когда есть проверка на `hasOwnProperty`.</s>
  Что-то этот пункт не захотел подтверждаться экспериментально.

## Для массива:

- Будут перебираться не только индексы, но и другие свойства. Если вместо массива окажется массивоподобный объект, то может попасться свойство length.
- Если подключены полифилы для массивов (что весьма вероятно), в браузерах, не умеющих делать скрытые свойства, в перебор попадут все эти функции.
- Перебираются только индексы, которые есть в массиве. Если элемент массива удалялся через delete, либо добавление в массив происходило по индексу после его конца, то отсутствующие индексы будут пропущены. Но порядок перебираемых индексов будет верным.

  ```
  var a = [undefined, , 4];
  a[7] = undefined;

  for (var i in a) { // 0 2 7
    console.log(i);
  }
  ```
- Перебор массива через for in по производительности уступает нормальному циклу в десятки раз.

## ES6

- Для перебора элементов массива (значений, не индексов!) ES6 вводит цикл for of:

  ```
  var a = [undefined, , 4];
  a[7] = undefined;

  for (var x of a) {
    console.log(x);
  }
  ```

  2 раза выводится `undefined`, затем `4` и ещё 5 раз `undefined`.