# JavaScript forin не пробегает по индексам массива

Tags: javascript, массивы

Если я создам массив таким образом `a=[1,2,12]`, то смогу пробежать по индексам так `for (var i in a)`, но если создать массив с помощью `new Array`, то ситуация меняется:

```
b=new Array(10);
for(var i in b) console.log(i);
```

`forin` перестает бегать по индексам массива. Что не так?

```js
"use strict";

document.body.innerHTML = "for a: ";
var a = [1, 2, 12];
for (var i in a)
  document.body.innerHTML += `${i} `;

document.body.innerHTML += "<br>for b:";

var b = new Array(10);
for (var i in b)
  document.body.innerHTML += `${i} `;
```

**UPD** Немного изменю вопрос. Можно создать массив двумя способами, получить эквивалентный результат, но при этом `forin` будет работать для этих массивом по разному. Покажу это на примере:

```js
"use strict"

var p=(s)=>document.body.innerHTML+=s;

var x = [undefined, undefined, undefined];
var y = new Array(3);

p(`${x.length} ${y.length}<br>`);

for (var i=0; i<3; i++) p(`${x[i] === y[i]} `);
p("<br>");

p("forin for x:");
for (var i in x) document.body.innerHTML += `${i} `;
p("<br>forin for y:");
for (var i in y) document.body.innerHTML += `${i} `;
```

Получается в чем-то все таки эти массивы отличаются. В чем?

Консоль в хроме их отображает по разному.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: наверное массив `b` пустой потому что

Comment: `alert(b)` выдает `,,,,,,,,,,`

Comment: Кажется единственный правильный ответ тут должен быть: никогда не ходите по массиву forin-ом

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
b=new Array(10);
```

данная строка создает 10 пустых элементов. Так делать нежелательно. Тут можно создать несколько элементов `b=new Array(10, 1, 6, 8)`; Так будет отрабатывать правильно. или если вы уже хотите создать один элемент, то тогда лучше это сделать так

```
var b = new Array();
b[0] = 10;
```

Comment: Я создаю именно массив с 10 элементами.

Comment: @SergeyPestov дак он пустой, память выделена, но данных нет, что он должен вывести по вашему? воздух?

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, обновил вопрос.

Comment: @SergeyPestov смотрите, вы вопрос обновили, а мой комментарий предыдущий, уже на него ответил) Место выделяется, но данных в нем нет, `undefined x N` означает что у вас `N` неопределенных значений в массиве. А в случае с `X` вы присваиваете элементам массива значение `undefined` что уже является значением, этим самым вы инициализируете значения по индексам массива

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, я понял о чем вы, но меня все равно смущает тот факт, что массивы совпадают как по количеству элементов так и по содержанию.

Comment: @SergeyPestov Нет не совпадают) В `X` не объявленные x3 количество массивов, а в `Y` объявлены как `undefined`. Это просто надо знать, на практике (если вы правильно пишите) у вас такое не произойдет. Да и выделять память на `N` количество элементов почти никогда не нужно, все делается динамически. Это придется признать как факт)

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, допустим дан массив `x` состоящий из одних `undefined`. Как можно определить пустой он или нет?

Comment: А также объявлен элемент или нет?

Comment: @SergeyPestov ты скажи цель которая тебе нужна, из неоткуда не возьмется массив с необъявленными элементами. Если у тебя есть практическая проблема, ты её опиши

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев,это так скажем жажда знаний. Хочу понять все тонкости JavaScript.

Comment: @SergeyPestov ну у тебя не будет такого на практике, да и наврятли ты будешь объявлять массивы через `new Array()` :))

Answer (score 3):

```
var b = new Array(10);
b[0] = "one"
b[1] = "two"
b[2] = "three"
for (var i in b)
  document.body.innerHTML += `${i} `;
```

`Выхлоп`

```
for b:
0 1 2
```

---

**UPD**

Скорее всего из-за того, что вы инициализируете массив `x` как `[undefined, undefined, undefined]`, если заменить это на `[,,,]` (3 запятых, прошу обратить внимание), то выхлоп получается идентичный

```
3 3
true true true 
forin for x:
forin for y:
```

Comment: не проверять `hasOwnProperty` плохо :)

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, спасибо, я не знал такой функции

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, в большинстве случаев нормально, _hasOwnProperty_ - довольно медленная функция, чтобы пхать ее во все циклы

Comment: @Grundy все относительно)))

Comment: @Grundy, ненормально. Особенно когда IE8 + полифилы es5.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что в массиве ничего нет. Так что перебирать нечего.

[В чём опасность использования for .. in для объекта или массива?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/512990/178988)

> Получается в чем-то все таки эти массивы отличаются. В чем?

В первом есть 3 элемента со значением `undefined`, а во втором пустота.