# Как пройтись по массиве циклом, тем самым проверяя инпут?

Tags: javascript, массивы, циклы

Есть вот такой код:

```
<input id="forpassword">
<input id="forlogin">




var users = [
        {"name":"Kurusa", "pass":"Kurusa123"},
        {"name":"Zhecky", "pass":"Zhecky123"},
        {"name":"Marko", "pass":"Marko123"},
        {"name":"Polo", "pass":"Polo123"}
    ];

    var login = document.getElementById('forlogin').value;
    var second = document.getElementById('forpassword').value;

    function testEnter() {
        for (var a in users) {
                if (login == a && second == a) {
                    alert('You did it');
                }
                else {
                    alert('Пробуй ще');
                }
            }
        }
```

А выше - инпуты и кнопка. В общем, цель такова, чтобы вместимость инпутов проверялась вот по этому массиву, но что-то идет не так.

Comment: Извините, не уточнила. Пока что хочу сделать проверку вот какой: если введенное имя и пароль соответствуют объектам в массиве, то alert('You did it'), иначе - второй вариант. Что идет не так: даже если ввожу правильно, всё равно второй вариант, и несколько раз

Comment: if (login == users[a].name && second == users[a].pass) {

Comment: если условие верно, то выход из цикла.

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, да, простите, не заметил, что не of, а in

Comment: Оно всё равно не работает. А ещё не могли бы подсказать  такое: при попытке использовать of, php storm считает это ошибкой. Для этого метода нужно что-то подключить, что ли?

Comment: добавил ответ, попробуй так. Что касается PhpStorm'a, то видимо он не в курсе es6.

Comment: спасибо огромное, но там как раз этот of. А PhpStorm можно как-то уведомить о существовании es6?

Comment: не, это браузерная штука. Тут либо есть либо нет, PhpStorm просто не знает такого синтаксиса, скорее всего его просто надо обновить (ну или lint'ер обновить, не знаю как там у phpStorm это работает). Переписал на старый манер.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var users = [
  {"name":"Kurusa", "pass":"Kurusa123"},
  {"name":"Zhecky", "pass":"Zhecky123"},
  {"name":"Marko", "pass":"Marko123"},
  {"name":"Polo", "pass":"Polo123"}
];

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', testEnter);

function testEnter() {
  var inUsers = false;
  var login = document.getElementById('forlogin').value;
  var second = document.getElementById('forpassword').value;

  for (var a = 0; a < users.length; a++) {
    if (login == users[a].name && second == users[a].pass) {
      inUsers = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  alert(inUsers ? 'You did it' : 'Пробуй ще');
}
```

```html
<input id="forlogin">
<input id="forpassword">
<button type="button">Check</button>
```

Comment: `users[a]` - либо делай нормальный цикл до длины, либо верни for-of, но тогда будет просто `a`.

Comment: @Qwertiy, можно подробнее? Почему нельзя break ? Или in тоже пришел с es6? Просто до недавних пор использовал только jQuery переборы, либо стандартный for(var i=0...)

Comment: `break` можно. я про конструкцию `for (var a in users) {` - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/513039/178988 А `in` - не es6, он просто тормоз))

Comment: Оно не работает, ребят :с не работает

Comment: @Qwertiy, сделал цикл для длины, завтра почитаю и вдумаюсь что там по ссылке, сейчас чот уже в голову ничего не лезет ))))

Comment: @Біпач, спокойствие, только спокойствие, сейчас в сниппет загоним и протестим.

Comment: А я даже знаю почему... dom-элементы не равны строкам :)

Comment: Заменил на сниппет, вроде все ок. Может проблема в том, что раньше сначала шло поле пароля, а потом логина? Я первые 2 раза тоже на этом попался.

Comment: Ну и вообще мы не видели как это триггерится у вас. По идее value надо брать перед тем, как проверять, а не при инициализации (переместил их в тело функции).

Comment: Спасибо огромное С:

Comment: @MedvedevDev, а можете пожалуйста объяснить к чему в цикле указна длинна массива?

Comment: @Біпач, стандарт, просто проходим по всему массиву `users`. Для этого нужно указать `var a = 0` (просто некая переменная которая потом будет изменяться с каждой итерацией), `a++` (после каждого прохода увеличиваем 'a' на +1), `a < users.length` (повторяем цикл пока 'a' меньше, чем кол-во элементов в массиве `users`). Таким образом мы проходим по всем элементам масива `users`. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Comment: Спасибо что объяснили. И ещё Вы писали "мы не видели как это триггерится у вас". Если Вам интересно, тогда вооот: http://kurusa.zhecky.net/lesson_08/