# добавление функционала в Javascript (поиск в массиве), не поддерживаемого IE

Tags: javascript, функции, internet-explorer, prototype, совместимость

Приветствую

Использую для поиска в массиве метод Array.prototype.find()

```
var dialogNode = xml.find(function(element){
    var objectParams = myGetTagParams(element.nodeName);

    return (objectParams.type == 'my:dialog');
});
```

но в IE этот функционал не поддерживается :( (а IE используют некоторые пользователи сайта)

поэтому для них пришлось переписать код

```
var dialogNode = '';

for (var index in xml)
{
    var element = xml[index];

    var objectParams = myGetTagParams(element.nodeName);

    if (objectParams.type == 'my:dialog')
    {
        dialogNode = element;
        break;
    }
}
```

Это не очень удобно, когда в разных частях сайта используются конструкции типа "если у пользователя один браузер - выполняй это, а если другой - выполняй это"

Подскажите, можно ли где-то при загрузке страницы, определив какой у пользователя браузер (или лучше - определив, доступен ли нужный функционал) добавить свой, если функционал недоступен, т.е. сделать примерно так

```
if (Array.prototype.find == undefined)
    Array.prototype.find = function(){}
```

?

И тогда смело в любом месте сайта можно вызывать функционал одним и тем же способом, хотя код для разных браузеров будет различным

Comment: да, примерно так и работают [полифилы](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Polyfill).

Comment: Уже есть [пример реализации](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill)

Comment: Grundy, добавил данный код
исполняю код раньше, чем любой другой, но полезли ошибки
такое чувство, что этот прототип прописался в другие функции массивов - например в извлечения элементов 

у меня в коде 
x = a[i]

а в x почему-то появляется не содержимое массива, а этот самый прототип

Comment: [В чём опасность использования for .. in для объекта или массива?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/512991/186999)

Answer (score 1):

Кажется разобрался!

Главное - если прототипа не существовало, приходится внедрять его несколько иным путём, чем показано в приведённых в вопросе примерах, а именно использовать Object.defineProperty:

```
if (!Array.prototype.find) {

    Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "find", {
        value: function(predicate) {

            if (this == null) {
                throw new TypeError('Array.prototype.find called on null or undefined');
            }

            if (typeof predicate !== 'function') {
                throw new TypeError('predicate must be a function');
            }

            var list = Object(this);
            var length = list.length >>> 0;
            var thisArg = arguments[1];
            var value;

            for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                value = list[i];
                if (predicate.call(thisArg, value, i, list)) {
                    return value;
                }
            }

            return undefined;
        },
    });
}
```

Comment: стоит добавить _почему_ этот метод решает проблему.

Comment: как я понял, потому что метода find в Array в IE нет и поэтому его нельзя переопределить сразу, для начала его надо определить/создать, что и делает команда defineProperty

Comment: Нет, не правильно понял, почитай что именно делает defineProperty, какие настройки передаются этой функции и какие у них значения по умолчанию.