# Prompt в массив

Tags: javascript, html

могу ли я сделать так,что из prompt каждая буква являлась 1 значением в массиве?

Comment: Прежде чем задать вопрос, убедитесь, что вы выполнили [тщательный поиск ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=Prompt+%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2+%5Bjavascript%5D). Поделитесь результатом вашего поиска и расскажите, что вы нашли и почему найденные ответы вас не устроили. Это продемонстрирует вашу способность думать самостоятельно, поможет избежать повторяющихся очевидных ответов и, самое важное, увеличит шансы на получение точного ответа!

Answer (score 2):

```js
var str = "abc "

// Не рабоатет с многобайтовыми символами
console.log(str.split(""))            // стандартный способ
console.log(str.match(/./g) || [])    // можно ограничить выбираемый набор символов

// Рабоатет с многобайтовыми символами
console.log([...str])                 // требуется поддержка браузером ES6
console.log(Array.from(str))          // можно подключить полифилл
console.log(str.match(/./gu) || [])   // требуется поддержка браузером ES6
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
.as-console-row-code.as-console-row-code { white-space: normal }
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var str = prompt("Enter a string");
var arr = (str || "").split("");
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Исходя из того, что `каждая буква` !== `любой символ`, я бы подкорректировал. Хотя, может ТС это и требуется

Answer (score 0):

По сути любой текст - это уже массив. Можно его перебором просмотреть, распихать в другой массив по буквам.

```js
var str = "Привет, человек";
for (char in str){
 console.log(str[char]);
};
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/513039/178988 - строк тоже касается.

Comment: @Qwertiy  Спасибо за ссылку.